# creacion de etiqueta tabla en javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, javascript-objeto, html-tabla, javascript-metodo

tengo un codigo donde mediante js muestro un registro y lo muestra en una lista tipica pero me gustaria que se mostrara en una tabla

```
 mensaje = '<p style= "font-family: arial, sans-serif; "> <b> se ha recibido una solicitud de usuario: </b></p><br>';

  mensaje += '<p style="font-family: arial, sans-serif;"><b>nombre del usuario a crear:  </b>'+login+'</p>';   
               
  mensaje += '<p style="font-family: arial, sans-serif;"><b>Comentario: </b> <b style="color: FF0000">'+comentario+' </b></p>';

 mensaje += '<p style="font-family: arial, sans-serif;"><b>Login solicitante </b>'+login_+'</p>';

 mensaje += '<p style="font-family: arial, sans-serif;"><b>Nombre del cliente </b>'+usuarioEliminar[0]. NOMBRE APELLIDO+'</p>';

mensaje += '<p style="font-family: arial, sans-serif;"><b>Telefono del cliente : </b>' +TELEFONO+'</p>';

mensaje += '<p style="font-family: arial, sans-serif;"><b>Correo del cliente: </b>'+usuarioEliminar[0].CORREO+'</p>';
```

de esa manera captura cada mensaje a mostrar... cuando recibo el mensaje me llega como el de la img 1 y me gustaria mostrarlo como el de la img 2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y por qué no usás `<table>`?

Comment: si se q es con table pero cuando intente hacerlo mas bien me dio error y estuve todo el dia de ayer intentado integrarlo

Comment: y el error fue...?

Comment: bueno ya borre la imagen del resltado pero me trado todo desordenado y en partes me mostraba el codigo y no mostraba el resultado

Comment: Probablemente porque había algún error de concatenación. Creeme que usando la etiqueta `<p>` te vas a complicar, teniendo en cuenta que `<table>` _ya está diseñado para tal motivo_.

Comment: la etiqueta p la estoy usando ahorita para mostrarlo como la img 1 porq no pude integrar el table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso pudieras usar css grid. Crearías un div que contenga el nombre de la propiedad y otro con su valor. Haces esto tantas veces según el número de pares propiedad-valor que deseas mostrar. Todos esos divs estarían dentro de un div padre con el siguiente css:

```
#DivPadre {
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
}
```

Y no hay ningún problema para representar los bordes internos y externos de la tabla. Para eso pudieras establecer un `background-color` al div padre de color rojo y los divs internos de color blanco (según muestras en la imagen) y usar las propiedades css `gap`, `padding`, `border`. Lo acomodas como desees, solo te doy una idea.

Por cierto en tu código de arriba repites muchas veces las mismas propiedades css (`font-family` en este caso). Pudieras agrupar todo eso en una regla css para que, cuando desees cambiar algún valor, solo lo cambies una vez. Recuerda que en esto de la programación es muy importante evitar repetir el mismo código una y otra vez porque sino es más difícil modificarlo y tus archivos serían más grandes y el navegador tardaría más en procesar el código. En proyectos pequeños esto es insignificante, pero es una mala práctica que es mejor evitar. Te lo digo por experiencia propia :)